# exposing an enum through a wrapper class in c#

Tags: c#, enums

I am writing a C# wrapper for a particularly difficult COM library. The COM interfaces uses enum extensively, and as such there are approximately 100 different enums.

What is the simplest way to expose the enum to users of my wrapper library without wholesale copy-and-paste of the COM library?

Something like `typedef` from C++ or inheriting the enum would be perfect, but I know neither exist in C#.

Comment: Doesn't [`tlbimp.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.71).aspx) do that for you?

Comment: No. Tblimp makes the COM types available in my code but it doesn't expose them to the users of my wrapper